# Python 2.7 string concatenation odd timing results

Tags: python, string-concatenation

The question has been asked about which is the fastest method of string concatenation, and very often the answer is `''.join()` or `%s`.  However, I just ran a test and am getting *significantly* faster times with `+=`, to the tune of less than 1% the time of any other option.

My question is this: why do my results differ so much from other answers I've read?  Is this case particularly unique?

*NOTE: I am running this in Python 2.7 and have no intention on migrating to 3 any time soon.*

**UPDATE:** Per @Coldspeed's comments, this code has been updated using `timeit`.  Results seem to be on par with previous run.

**Code**:

```
import timeit

print '+=        : ' + \
str(timeit.Timer("new_string=''\nlong_string='lksjdliu3l9809c8098welkjwelrkjv99v8wfwlkj3'\n" +
    "for i in range(10000): new_string += long_string").timeit(number = 5))

print "''.join() : " + \
str(timeit.Timer("new_string=''\nlong_string='lksjdliu3l9809c8098welkjwelrkjv99v8wfwlkj3'\n" +
    "for i in range(10000): new_string = ''.join((new_string, long_string))").timeit(number = 5))

print "%s        : " + \
str(timeit.Timer("new_string=''\nlong_string='lksjdliu3l9809c8098welkjwelrkjv99v8wfwlkj3'\n" +
    "for i in range(10000): new_string = '%s%s' %(new_string, long_string)").timeit(number = 5))

print "{}      : " + \
str(timeit.Timer("new_string=''\nlong_string='lksjdliu3l9809c8098welkjwelrkjv99v8wfwlkj3'\n" +
    "for i in range(10000): new_string = '{}{}'.format(new_string, long_string)").timeit(number = 5))
```

**Results** (run multiple times, always roughly the same):

```
+=        : 0.00943579411126
''.join() : 2.76879656576
%s        : 2.13202393986
{}        : 1.60845005433
```

Comment: Consider using `timeit`. More accurate.

Comment: You're not using `str.join` properly. `new_string = ''.join(long_string for i in range(10000))` *is* faster than `+=`.

Comment: @pshep123 Quite possibly. Their mechanisms are very different I believe.

Comment: @vaultah - thanks for the heads up, good to know.  However, my example is just that, an example.  In reality I'll be adding multiple strings together that aren't just based on a list comprehension generated in a loop.  Does that change your response?

Comment: Your tests are a little off because you are never joining more than two strings. join will shine when concatenation is required for more than two values.